# pgfplots cannot read table from file

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to plot using `pgfplots` from a file containing two colums separated by tabs.

```
Tweak   Probability
4   0.0065935332
5   0.0006670277
6   0.0002015741
7   6.31090951863062E-005
8   0.000012437
9   0.000003721
10  1.02492049264844E-006
11  2.40164808733254E-007
12  0.000000056
13  1.525040714335E-008
14  0.000000003
15  9.31322573422856E-010
16  4.65661286657218E-010
17  5.82076609134674E-011
18  7.27595761413049E-012
19  7.27595761407755E-012
```

When I do `\addplot table[x=Tweak, y=Probability] { myfile.dat };`, I get this error:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '" img/doubletweak.dat "'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).
```

I tried doing what it says, to no avail. When I copy and paste the table and use it in-line, the plot works fine. What might be wrong?

Comment: Start by removing the spaces around the file name: `{myfile.dat}`

Comment: Ha ha, how stupid. This was the issue. Would you supply answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TeX does not (normally) ignore spaces in arguments. Thus `{ myfile.dat }` and `{myfile.dat}` are not the same: remove the spaces around the file name and it should be found.